# php-fpm and nginx session problems

Tags: session, nginx, php

I've been having this problem for the past week or so. I've been working on a PHP project that relies HEAVILY on Sessions. For some reason we've been having troubles with the sessions saving the past few days. Any idea why?

Here's the error:

```
Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_mmd0ru5pl2h2h9bummcu1uu620, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in Unknown on line 0 Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
Warning: session_start(): open(/tmp/sess_mmd0ru5pl2h2h9bummcu1uu620, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

nginx version:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.0.11
```

PHP-FPM config:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix.

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Default Value: none
pid = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; Default Value: /var/log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
;daemonize = yes

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; See /etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

nginx.conf:

```
#######################################################################
#
# This is the main Nginx configuration file.
#
# More information about the configuration options is available on
#   * the English wiki - http://wiki.nginx.org/Main
#   * the Russian documentation - http://sysoev.ru/nginx/
#
#######################################################################

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Module - directives that cover basic functionality
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

user              nginx nginx;
worker_processes  5;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Events Module
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpEventsModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# HTTP Core Module
#
#   http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        server {
                listen 80;
                server_name stats.smilingdevil.com;

                error_page   404   /404.php;

                root /var/www;

                access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

                location / {
                        set $page_to_view "/index.php";
                        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
                        root /var/www/;
                        index index.php;
                }

                location @rewrites {
                        if ($uri ~* ^/([a-z0-9]+)$) {
                                set $page_to_view "/$1.php";
                                rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /$1.php last;
                        }
                }

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please check /tmp directory mode, it should be 777. Also check selinux audit.log ( if installed )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found that my php.ini was attempting to save sessions to /var/lib/php/session rather than /tmp

So check your ini file and see where they're being saved to (or set it to somewhere else); then make sure that directory is writeable by the appropriate processes

Comment: Why does some installations use /var/lib/php5/ and some use /tmp... etc?

Comment: Yeah I had the same problem, except to /var/lib/php/5.5/session.
@CMCDragonkai I think its parameters you give it when you compile it.

Comment: Note, when you upgrade NginX through yum (CentOS) it defaults to change the ownership of /var/lib/php to "apache" -- wrong ownership! This has caused me trouble before.

Comment: This is not `nginx` or `apache` that are messing with session path. It is `php` that assumes it is used with `apache` that is causing the problem. Many people have decided to "punt" and just use `/tmp` for session data. This is relatively insecure. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: For those who wonder, php.ini parameter is `session.save_path`.

Answer (score 28):

Just change the ownership of /var/lib/php/session/ to nginx from apache instead of giving a world read.

```
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session/
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When the `php` package gets updated, the permissions will be reverted.

Comment: The default ownership on /var/lib/php/session/ is usually apache -or- www-data so if using nginx you should always stat the folder on upgrade. Again I propose you give group permissions to root and user to nginx.

i.e chown -R root:nginx /var/lib/php/session/ as opposed to chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/session/ as I had posted ealier

Comment: That doesn't work long term. Many package manager will change the permissions on `/var/lib/php/session` on any update. Requiring an extra manual step after any update is a recipe for failure in the future. I find it's easier to just add user `nginx` to the `apache` group. See next answer

Answer (score 15):

## TL;DR: Add `nginx` user to `apache` group

RHEL has decided that `/var/lib/php/session` is owned by the `php` package. That package has decided that it will always recreate the `/var/lib/php/session` directory when installed and will always return the directory to being owned by `root` with group set to `apache` with full permissions for each and no permissions for anything else. Therefore, while many suggested solutions here suggest changing the permissions of `/var/lib/php/session`, that will cause problems in the future.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1146552

The RHEL suggested way of fixing this issue is to create your own session directory wherever you'd like to store it and set the permissions as necessary. Future php updates won't affect that new location and everything should stay working.

An alternative that has worked quite well for me is to simply add `nginx` to the `apache` group.

Comment: +1 add nginx to apache group, unless you're running apache and nginx as mutually-untrusting users.  That should almost never happen.

Comment: I updated the user property in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf to apache.  It was simpler since the session files were mod 600 apache:apache.

Comment: @StephenJazdzewski Idk, seems weird to me to have Nginx running as user `apache`. I have not seen session files with that mode. It's always been `0660` for me.

Comment: I'm tempted to remove the apache user/group, since I don't *use* Apache...

Comment: @Matthew you'll have fewer headaches if you work *with* what the package maintainers prescribe. Sure, it can be not ideal, but dealing with a headache you made for yourself in a year is much more annoying than just ignoring it. Regardless, the next upgrade might recreate the group anyway...

Comment: @CameronTacklind okay, but it soundes like the package maintainers perscribe that I use apache2, when I in-fact do not wish to use apache2, and would like to continue using nginx.

Comment: @Matthew where are you seeing that they "prescribe that [you] use apache2"?

Comment: @CameronTacklind I don't see it anywhere, hence "it sounds like".

Comment: @Matthew Are you saying that because you don't use Apache, you don't want a group named `apache` on your machine? I can understand that. I gave up on that fight a long time ago.

Answer (score 9):

this error occured due to the user which run php process may not have permission to write on /tmp directory

to make it writeable by all user use this commend

```
chmod 777 /tmp
```

another reason which causes the same issue is read only file system

if /dev/sda1 is mounted on /tmp and due to heavy write your file system may become read only...

to make it rewritable again use this command

```
mount -t ext3 -o rw,remount /dev/sda1 /tmp
```

Comment: i thought it... most users are mounting /tmp drive on seperate volume... i said "if".. and before posting any quetion on stackoverflow checkout your program code first...

Comment: @SmilingDevil: Voting people down who try there best to help is a bit harsh don't you think?

Comment: I think this is a little too loose of an answer, the answer below by Joe is solves the problem without opening up the entire tmp folder.

Comment: `/tmp` is *supposed* to be read-write by all users.  (The correct octal permissions for it are 1777, not 0777 - the difference is the "sticky" bit, which makes it so user A can't delete user B's files.)

Answer (score 9):

Chris Rutledge is right,
php some times is saving sesions on /var/lib/php/session/ directory
check your php.ini file or
create the directory with 777 rights

```
mkdir /var/lib/php/session
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session
```

Comment: this worked for me; upgrading a CentOS 7 server caused the permissions on this folder to go wrong; cart was not holding items, users could not login and admin site was not accessible (although login info was being validated).

Comment: Thanks for that comment, it fixed my session problem too. But is that no security issue to set the 777 chmod on that session folder? thanks in advance

Comment: i am not sure about the security on this solutions plus i did the same but it seems to be revert back everytime server reboots

Comment: `chown nginx.nginx fpm` `chown nginx.nginx fpm/session` `chmod 777 session`

Comment: I had a problem that my Ubuntu16.04/PHP7.1 installation was keeping session files in /tmp, which was wiped on reboot, so I changed the session folder to `/var/lib/php/sessions`, and this worked. Thanks.

Comment: Chris's answer and your answer both fixed my issue Thank you guys.

Comment: Please don't open security holes with 777.  At least use 1777!  But even 1777 isn't ideal.  It is best to use 700 or 750 with write permissions of the nginx user.

Answer (score 4):

Seems I found something interesting on the Linux. In the chroot php-cgi make same errors when some PHP software try to read/write session. I thought this could be permission issue, but after set 777 and set owner of the webserver to the "/tmp" and set it in the After many hours it found that "urandom" device in the "/dev" needed to work it. Just make sure that it found or copy/make it and change permissions temporary (just for check and then change to safely):

```
chmod 777 /dev/urandom
```

Strange to me that it wasn't required in some PHP5.x version but in some PHP7.x need to be there.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Seems the PHP session files need random generator device /dev/urandom for make different file names, so your web server should access the /dev/urandom (on the server in the Linux system). Is it ok?

Comment: "chmod 777 /dev/urandom" can help in this case (for check only and then permissions must be fixed)

Comment: I gave you a +1 for that insight.

Comment: Using /dev/urandom instead is an upgrade to PHP security.  It can hurt performance (latency) if there isn't enough entropy and there's no hardware RNG.  If you're not in need of crypto-grade hashes you can ln -s /dev/random /dev/urandom instead, but you might need it later and forget that you put that hack in place - so be careful & make notes.

Answer (score 1):

I just went through an upgrade of PHP on CentOS. I had to change /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and update the php_value[session.save_path] variable and set it to /tmp

```
php_value[session.save_path]    = /tmp
```

This works fine.
I don't think this will be a security hazard.

Comment: If you trust everything running on your server, there is no hazard. But trusting everything on your server is a hazard. You should not do this. Compartmentalize when possible. When something goes wrong, it can't spread.

Answer (score 1):

You might get this error when you'r using NGINX and the server gives permission to apache instead of nginx.

My fix is:

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/lib/php/
```

With chown you are changhing the owner of that specific folder and -R means its recursive.

Comment: This however won't persist if the `php` package updates. See my answer for a persistent fix ;)