# CakePHP 2 sessions ending abruptly/prematurely

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have a few CakePHP 2.5.1 websites running on a production LAMP environment with PHP 5.3.29 and MySQL 5.6 (I know, it's old stuff). They use **Auth** to protect the access to them to only registered users. **These websites have had no issues for years**.

**Recently** we started getting complains from users that they are being kicked out of those sites when seemingly they shouldn't be, it even happened to myself once. I'm talking getting the typical message that we display when someone tries to access a protected page once their **session expires** and they get taken to the login page. Only that those sessions are expiring quicker than they should. We use database sessions for these sites, here's the config:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
                                    'defaults' => 'database',
                                    'handler' => array('model' => 'cake_sessions'),
                                    'timeout' => 60
                                    ));

Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

The weirdest thing is that after getting kicked out, if you log in again and try to access a page that you had not accessed in your previous session, you **get kicked out again** to the login page. But if you access a page that you had accessed before getting kicked out in the previous session, then you can access it no problem. I presume this might be related to **caching** but I had never seen something like this happen in these sites before, so I thought I'd mention it just in case.

The **code** of those sites **has not changed in years**. The **only thing** that's changed is that the server where those websites are located had some **PHP configuration** changed where they **enabled PHP-FPM**, and it does *seem* like these issues started around the same time, but I don't know how to make a connection between that and the sessions. Also I don't think we can have that disabled.

I've been doing some troubleshooting, printing session variables while using these sites, looking at the database table that handles sessions, verifying session IDs, timeouts, cookies, etc and everything seems OK as far as I can tell. Sessions get automatically refreshed when I navigate to other pages, they show the correct duration, Cakephp cookies show correct session IDs, etc. **I have not managed to replicate the issue or found anything wrong in the code, database, cookies, or PHP session**. But maybe I'm not looking in the right places.

**So in reality I have 2 questions:**

1. Does anyone know what might be going on here with the sessions? What can cause a premature end of a session?
2. Can anyone suggest a way for me to troubleshoot this? Replicate the issue somehow?

Comment: I feel for you! I've had the same thing occur before I gutted my Cake2 apps. Here's something you could look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9203320/php-fpm-and-nginx-session-problems/50519674 ... it's not exactly your problem but might give you some other things to try. We had to revert our Cake2 PHP-FPM back to Apache mod PHP

Comment: @hppycoder thank you! Did you try the suggested answers and that still didn't work for you? I can see if it would be possible to get PHP-FPM disabled if that's going to be easier.

Comment: I came into SO late and didn't see the answers. We pulled the FPM install after production was breaking and we couldn't figure out why. Moved one of our stacks over to FPM to get the concurrency higher but the other app we struggled with

Comment: @hppycoder ok thank you, I appreciate your input